# FB Application post on user news feed as application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

Not sure if this is possible (or if there is a similar way to do that):

I have an Facebook application that when a user installs it I want to generate news feeds to show to this user and only.

I would like that the news feed posts are personified by the application and not the user itself.

Is this possible?

If not, is there a way to achieve the same thing with a FB Page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to write on a user's Timeline on behalf of an App or a Page, the posts will always be attributed to a user.

If you need to communicate directly with a user the best options are to either get their email address from the API or use [Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/)